# Linux : Rename files that ends with live.conf to dev.conf

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I have list of files which ends with -live.conf.
e.g.
`admin-live.conf`
`user-live.conf`

Above files should be renamed to:
`admin-dev.conf`
`user-dev.conf`

please help me how can I achieve with single command.

Comment: `rename 's/(.*)-live.conf$/$1-dev.conf/' *`

Comment: @MarounMaroun you don't have to provide (.*)- as it will be vry less common that we will have live.conf in our file name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is `rename` stand-alone utility by perl package.

usage :-

```
rename -n -v 's/live.conf/dev.conf/' *
```

Comment: Cool. Better than the one I suggested above.

Comment: you can say that but there is limitation. as stated above comment.

Answer (score 2):

Proper **find** + **bash** solution:

```
find . -type f -name "*-live.conf" -exec bash -c \
'dir_n=${0%/*}/; fn=${0##*/}; mv "$0" "$dir_n${fn/-live/-dev}"; ' {} \;
```